# Redirecting Green Plum COPY Errors to a file

Tags: copy, greenplum

The COPY command in the Green plum,can log the errors in to an error table. Is there any way where I can log these errors in a file.

Thanks
Ganesh.R

Comment: Can't you just copy the table to a file?

Comment: Won't it be an additional work,involving I/O twice. Instead is there any option in which green plum writes directly to the file.

Answer (score 2):

The COPY command only allows you to redirect errors to an error table.  What you could do is set up an external writable table and use that as your error table for the COPY command.